# Change or convert only text of label without changing their values in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, label

This is my code below:

```
<form name="mainform" id="mainform" class="form_step" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<ol>
<li id="list_cp_you_are">
 <div class="labelwrapper">
    <label><a href="#" tip="You are" tabindex="999"><div class="helpico"></div></a>You are: <span class="colour">*</span></label>
 </div>
```

Expected code:

```
<form name="mainform" id="mainform" class="form_step" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<ol>    
    <li id="list_cp_you_are">
 <div class="labelwrapper">
    <label><a href="#" tip="You are" tabindex="999"><div class="helpico"></div></a>I am: <span class="colour">*</span></label>
 </div>
```

I just want to convert or change only "You are:" text to "I am:" text from label tags without changing their values that too with immediate effect on page loading.

Anyone plz helpme..

Answer (score 2):

Get the anchor and the textNode will be the nextSibling :

```
$('#mainform label a').each(function() {
    this.nextSibling.nodeValue = this.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace('You are', 'I am');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9p2V/)